# How does Eclipse know if a Tomcat server is running?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp

I've run into an odd situation with Eclipse Luna on Centos. I have configured a Tomcat 7.0 server, using project metadata for the configuration file. (actually TomEE, but I don't think that should matter). When I start the server from within Eclipse, I can see in the console window that it starts up, and I can confirm that the server is running, by interacting with it, but the legend displayed in the Servers window never changes from "Starting....." to "Started", and Eclipse times out the start operation with, "The server failed to start within ... seconds."

How, normally, does Eclipse determine whether or not a server that it owns has started successfully?  And what might be going on here?

[edited to add:] The same problem occurs with TomEE 1.7.1 and a recent TomEE 1.7.2-SNAPSHOT, and the Eclipse version is:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that my server was configured not to listen on any http ports, only on https ports.  The eclipse plugin wants to find an http port on which it can ping the server to see if it's running. If there is no http port configured, the plugin silently fails. This is probably a bug and I will report it... rather than silently failing, the plugin should complain about the lack of an http port.

More specifically, looking at the Eclipse plugin code at https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.servertools/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core/tomcatcore/org/eclipse/jst/server/tomcat/core/internal/TomcatServerBehaviour.java around line 540 (look for the comment "//ping server for startup") I see that the plugin is looking for an http port on which it can ping the server to see if it is live.

Answer (score 1):

There is a timeout option in seconds in the eclipse server configuration. If it is lower than required by default, you will run into this issue. Update it with a value which is reasonable for your application. Check [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fttimeout.html) for further details.

Comment: I can set the timeout option for a ridiculously high value -- the server starts, is running just fine, but somehow Eclipse doesn't know that it has started, and therefore ties it out.

Comment: which Target Runtime did you use for tomEE?

Comment: I did not select "workbench default JRE"; I selected  "java-1.7.0-0penjdk-1.7.0.75.x86_64"

Comment: Sorry I meant the template server target runtime (apache tomcat 6, 7 ...)

Comment: and what is you tomEE version?

Comment: The tomEE version is 1.7.2-SNAPSHOT as of a couple of days ago. (yeah, bleeding edge and all that...)

Comment: And was it OK with 1.7.1 ?

Comment: I will grab a 1.7.1 and report back in about an hour

Comment: Also fails with 1.7.1 and a fresh install of Eclipse

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you use a specific profile for tomEE 1.7.1?

Comment: I use the tomee-plus profile, but I have a nonstandard logging environment: I followed these instructions http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2012/11/logging-with-slf4j-and-logback-in.html (except that instead of using setenv.sh, I set the classpath by  editing the Eclipse launch configuration for the server. 

Do you know how Eclipse tells whether the server has started or not? That would help me isolate the problem -- I downloaded the zipped sources for the WTP server adapters and started looking around, but I don't really know where to look there.

Comment: (See my answer -- problem was that I had configured Tomcat with only https ports listening and no port listening to http; Eclipse didn't like that because it looks for an http port on which to ping the tomcat server to see if it's running.

Comment: Yes. I've seen it and upvoted it. Now that you said it, it should have been one of the first things I should have checked ;) Note that in the meanwhile, I've found this article that could have helped debugging: http://blog.vogella.com/2010/02/16/tomcat-unable-to-start/ . However, in your case, it is definitely a WTP bug.

Comment: The  bug has been on the books since 2007: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205867